# Authenticate user via web service in Android app

Tags: .net, android, web-services, sql-server-2008

I have created a web service that allows a user to authenticate his username and password. It returns "Success" when both username and password and correct. Now I need to make an Android app that does almost the same thing by taking a username and password via EditText fields and authenticating the user by calling the web service I have created.

I have created my database in SQL Server 2008 and I have used C#/.NET to create my webservice
Here is the [web service code](http://pastebin.com/M4XKLEPe)

Can anyone tell me how to go about creating the Android app?

Thanks

Comment: You are going to need some mechanism to persist the users session. After the user has logged in, how do you know that he is authenticated?

Comment: @aromero : Yes ur right I need to create a session but is it possible to do that in Android and with the technologies I am using?

Answer (score 1):

The [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) class should do what you want if you're looking for session maintenance after authentication.  If you're looking for a SOAP library, there's nothing on Android, but others have had luck with [kSOAP](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I am new to Android so I have some doubts.How do I use HttpClient ? How will I pass the url of my web service so that my Android app uses it for authentication after I enter username and password in EditText fields ?

Comment: Something to the effect of:

    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    request = new HttpGet(url);
    response = client.execute(request);

Comment: There is a fork of kSOAP for Android support here http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/